# RDJDBC::dbConnect failing to connect to HiveServer2 (kerberos +sasl)

Tags: r, hadoop, jdbc, kerberos, rjdbc

I am trying to connect to Hive2 using RJDBC but it failing with "GSS initiate failed". However same things working fine using beeline client. Any idea what may have caused different behavior when running both on same node with same credentials?

drv <- RJDBC::JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", cp, "`")

### following is just for illustrative purpose as I wanted to show what all parameter I am using as JDBC url.

conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://node1:10000/default;principal=hive/hive_node@REALM;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=store_path;trustStorePassword=store_password", "user", "password")

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  :
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://:10000/default;principal=hive/hive_node@REALM;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=store_path;trustStorePassword=store_password: GSS initiate failed

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for you, but... look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477466/error-when-connect-to-impala-with-jdbc-under-kerberos-authrication/42506620#42506620) about the details of configuring Kerberos authentication for Hive/Impala JDBC *(note also that "user" and "password" connection args are ignored by Kerberos auth)*

The post assumes that you have the password stored in a "keytab" file, and use it to create a private Kerberos ticket. If you want to use the default, public ticket instead, then change the JAAS conf accordingly *(i.e. `useTicketCache=true useKeyTab=false` and no `keyTab` entry)*

And to pass the configuration to Java from your R code, the easiest way is to set the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` env variable **before** anything else bootstraps the RJava initialization

```
Sys.setenv("JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS"="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/Path/To/jaas.conf -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false")
```

PS: on Windows the path would look like `C:/Path/To/jaas.conf` (Java converts slashes to backslashes automatically; that's easier that escaping each and every backslash because of the way R Strings interpret `\`)

---

Final note: if any jerk tags this with *"answers should not rely on links"*, since the aforementioned link points to another post of mine in S.O., then he/she is really a jerk, and I will gladly tell him/her to his/her face, loudly and with exotic words.