# Error when connect to impala with JDBC under kerberos authrication

Tags: authentication, kerberos, jdbctemplate, cloudera-cdh, impala

I create a class SecureImpalaDataSource that extends DriverManagerDataSource, and use `UserGroupInformation.doAs()` to get a Connection to impala with keytab file. But I get the error as follow:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]ImpalaJDBCDriver Error
>   initialized or created transport for authentication:
>   [Simba]ImpalaJDBCDriver Unable to connect to server: null.

But I am successful when I get the connection with kerberos ticket cache in a test demo. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is that the HOST and the FQDN in my URL are inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

Forget about the Hadoop UGI: a JDBC driver just needs the raw JAAS configuration to create a Kerberos ticket on-the-fly *(with `useKeyTab` raised and `useTicketCache` lowered)*.

**System properties**

- `java.security.krb5.conf` => (optional) non-defaut Kerberos conf
- `java.security.auth.login.config` => JAAS config file
- `javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly`  => must be forced to "false" *(the default has changed in some Java release, duh)*

**Sample JAAS conf file, Impala/Hive Cloudera drivers**
Here with a Windows path in Java-style notation.

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
    required
  useTicketCache=false
  doNotPrompt=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="file:C:/blah/blah/dummy.keytab"
  principal="dummy@SOME.REALM"
  debug=false;
};
```

**Sample JAAS conf file, Apache Hive driver**
Just change section name from `Client` to `com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate`
*PS: you can stuff multiple sections in the same conf file; this means that you can define a "global" conf and use it with multiple tools & drivers & libs, with consistent settings.*

**Debugging**

- `sun.security.krb5.debug` => set to "true"
- `java.security.debug`=> set to "gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext"

Comment: thanks a lots.  
although your answer would not help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter saved me what looked like a major headache with `javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false` hint!

Answer (score 1):

One way to authentication your jdbc connection is using ugi.doAs. Here is the sample code:

```
// 1. login use keytab
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "XXX.COM");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "kdcXXX");
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI("test", "test.keytab");

// 2. create impala jdbc connection
Class.forName(JDBCDriverName);
conn = (Connection) ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object>() {
  public Object run() {
    Connection tcon = null;
    try {
      tcon = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tcon;
  }
});

// 3. execute query using conn
......
```