# Issue connecting RStudio (but not R) to Hive with Kerberos

Tags: r, jdbc, hive, rstudio, kerberos

I'me trying to connect RStudio to Hive that has Kerberos authentication. If I run the below in an R script called from the command line, it works.

```
library("DBI")
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

cp = c("/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-service.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar"
, "/u01/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar")
.jinit(classpath=cp)

drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" , "hive-jdbc.jar" )

conn <- dbConnect(drv , "jdbc:hive2://XXXX:10000/default;principal=hive/XXXX@XXXXX";auth-kerberos)
```

If I run the exact same script in RStudio, I get an error:

```
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
```

If I run system('klist') in RStudio, it shows I have a valid ticket. It seems RStudio isn't able to identify the ticket but R is. Any ideas?

Comment: Which OS are you running on? What tool did you use to generate the ticket? Did you tinker with the env variable `KRB5CCNAME`?

Comment: OS is Red Hat 6.5. Used kinit to generate the ticket. The variable KRB5CCNAME isn't set/exists when I run Sys.getenv()

Comment: Try to force some Java system properties, that `.jinit` cannot handle, with an env variable e.g. `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true"` >> for the props that might make a difference, cf. my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477466/error-when-connect-to-impala-with-jdbc-under-kerberos-authrication/42506620

Comment: Note that if you must get down to the JAAS config file, in your case, the subject name should be `com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate` (cf. Hive driver) and  it should contain `useTicketCache=true useKeyTab=false` and no "keyTab" entry

Comment: Side note: you should use the placeholder `_HOST` in the URL, i.e. `...;principal=hive/_HOST@XXXXX` because it's easier, and also more generic *(i.e. if you ever migrate to a High Availability setup, you can't know in advance for which host you will be requesting a Kerberos service ticket)*

Comment: Adding the environment variable worked! Can now access Hive through RStudio :) Thanks so much

Comment: OK, I just posted a formal answer, with more context. Could be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some boring stuff first, to put things into context, then the solution.

- Kerberos: it's complicated by nature *(think cryptography <sup>network</sup>)*, even without considering that Microsoft has its own implementation and extensions
- Java and Kerberos: it's even more complicated *(only partial support, subtle changes in Java versions, etc.)*
- Hadoop and Java and Kerberos: it's complicated and ugly *(read the GitBook "Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate" if you really want to lose your sanity)* and it's even worse on Windows cf. lack of an official build for the required Hadoop "native libs"
- Hive and JDBC and Kerberos: the good news is that you don't need the Hadoop "ugly" part **unless** you are using the Apache JDBC driver on Windows *(hint: ditch it and opt for the Cloudera JDBC driver!)*; the bad news is that you may need raw JAAS configuration and specific Java system properties
- R and Java/JDBC: it works quite well, except that sometimes you want to pass specific Java system properties to the JVM -- either at launch time or at run time -- but `.jinit` does not support that AFAIK, you must resort to a workaround

---

There is one **Java system property** that must be set for Kerberos auth to work in JDBC, and it's not always set by default.
But you can't set that Java property from R directly; you have to set an **environment variable** *(either before starting R, or from R code but before `.jinit`)*

***Option 1:*** from a Linux shell script, before starting R...

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly‌​=false"
```

***Option 2:*** from your R code...

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly‌​=false")
.jinit(...)
```

---

Now, that may not be sufficient in all cases. Maybe you need to use a specific Kerberos config because your Hadoop cluster uses its own KDC. Maybe you don't want to use the default Kerberos ticket, but instead authenticate as a service account, using a password stored in a keytab file.
And maybe you need some debugging information because, well, shit happens *(and security libraries are quite secretive by default, not to make things too easy for hackers, I suppose...)*

Please refer to [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477466/error-when-connect-to-impala-with-jdbc-under-kerberos-authrication/42506620#42506620) for more information about **advanced Java configuration for Hive/Impala JDBC with Kerberos**.

And be careful when setting the environment variable: simulate a Java command-line i.e. `-Dsome.key=value -Dsome.other.key=blahblah`; in shell script, use quotes (because of the separating space); in R code, use a single string, no array.