# Configuring Kerberos authentication to run Impala queries as part of test automation in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, kerberos, impala

We have a module of java-Spark code that runs impala queries. As part of automation, i would like to have a junit that runs impala queries and compares the results with expected. Here the issue is need to pass through kerberos authentication to be able to run the impala queries in Jenkins. 
One possible way I can think is install Kerberos client on Jenkins ,create ticket manually and place it in cache. Have that junit use the ticket in cache file for authentication
Can anyone please tell me if there is any better alternative?

Comment: Use a JAAS config file to request a private, volatile Kerberos ticket to be created whenever a JDBC connection is attempted -- using a keytab file _(which is effectively equivalent to a password)_ for your test account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42506620/5162372

Comment: I am doing just the same as you have detailed in the attached thread. I had to get impala queries working in local on my Windows and for that, installed kerberos client , created ticket using kinit and used ticket cache. It all works fine. Now I want to run the same queries in Jenkins for each build. I tried if it would work with just the keytab file but it didnt work. May be I could install kerberos client and do the same steps as on my Windows but that is the last thing I want to do. Could you please let me know if you can suggest any alternatives?

Comment: Also this still remains a question to me as to when it would work with keytab and in what cases I need to generate ticket manually and use ticket cache. On my local Windows I had to generate ticket manually but on another Linux machine it worked with the keytab. Both are not principals.