# Kerberos java to impala keytab authentication with JAAS Configuration

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, jdbctemplate, jaas, keytab

I am trying to connect to Impala DB using kerberos KeyTab authentication and JAAS configuration.

I am already able to connect to Impala DB by setting System property - "java.security.auth.login.config" to JAAS config file. And it  works perfectly. Here is the working code:

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "false");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5ConfPath);
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasPath);

org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keyTabPath);

DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(DatabaseConfig.class.getClassLoader());
return dataSourceBuilder.build();
```

Problem is that JAAS config requires absolute path to keytab file. In my case this path will vary environment to environment and I do not want to maintain different jaas.config for each environment.

So I took programmatic approach of generating JAAS config. I am able to create "javax.security.auth.login.Configuration" object and setting it using
*javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.setConfiguration(jaasConfig);*

But when I run the code with this change it fails to pick the JAAS configuration and fails with below exception:

> Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]ImpalaJDBCDriver Error
>   creating login context using ticket cache: Unable to obtain Principal
>   Name for authentication.

**Can anybody please explain why code is running fine when configuration is set via System property but not working when it is being set programmatically.**

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "false");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", krb5ConfPath);

javax.security.auth.login.Configuration jaasConfig = createJaasConfig(keyTabPath);
             javax.security.auth.login.Configuration.setConfiguration(jaasConfig);

org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(principal, keyTabPath);

DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(DatabaseConfig.class.getClassLoader());
return dataSourceBuilder.build();
```

This is how I am creating JAAS Config:

```
private static javax.security.auth.login.Configuration createJaasConfig(final String keyTabPath) throws Exception {

        // Create entry options.
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put("useTicketCache", "false");
        options.put("doNotPrompt", "true");
        options.put("useKeyTab", "true");
        options.put("debug", "false");
        // options.put("storeKey", "true");
        options.put("principal", "user@DOMAIN.COM");
        options.put("keyTab", keyTabPath);

        // Create entries
        AppConfigurationEntry[] entries = {
            new AppConfigurationEntry(
                Krb5LoginModule.class.getCanonicalName(),
                AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
                options
            )
        };

        // Create configuration
        return new javax.security.auth.login.Configuration() {
            @Override
            public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
                return entries;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: If the raw JAAS config is used to create a process-private Kerberos ticket, why do you create another process-private ticket with static `UserGroupInformation` object _(which is a Hadoop-specific wrapper around JAAS)_?

Comment: To enable debug traces about the way JAAS interprets its config (incl. silent errors), cf. the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42506620/5162372

Comment: Hi @SamsonScharfrichter, i am sorry but i did not understand that UserGroupInformation part. What I have understood till now is that UserGroupInformation will eventually perform Subject.doAs for connection. For the log part I enabled those properties already. I can attach logs here if you want.

Comment: UGI is part of the Hadoop stack. It's used by Hadoop client libs. But the JDBC drivers don't use the Hadoop clients libs, they use standard JAAS instead - especially the Cloudera drivers that have _no_ dependency against Hadoop JARs _(developed with commercial SIMBA SDK)_; for the Apache driver it's not 100% true because it reuses some Kerberos utility methods, which is a pain on Windows BTW